# Unable to get LinkedIn library to work

Tags: php

I have tried to use this LinkedIn library

```
https://github.com/CuelogicTech/social-media-api/tree/LinkedIn
```

I got the link from this article here:

```
http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/manage-linkedin-profile-using-linkedin-api-with-oauth-2-0-3/
```

However, it seems to be outdated, buggy and not working anymore.

For example, in the linkedin_app.php file the  file in require call `require_once('LinkedIn.OAuth2.class');` miss the `.php` extension.

Can somebody suggest a similar simple LinkedIn library I can use with PHP to share messages on LinkedIn?

My app is authorized I got all the tokens and w_share scope. I just need to find a simple PHP library that will offer some functions to post to linkedin profile some messages from the script instead of writing everything from scratch.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client

Comment: I am unable to use it. My framework doesnt use composer, so, incuding the dependencies is not possible ;( . I have checked the vendors and there are like 8 different things like guzzle, hamtest etc. Is there any simple LinkedIn library where I will put the client id and secret and atuhentification token and I will have some functins to post to pulse or get some info etc. ?